# Template of old research document

Tags: templates

I've been looking at this PDF, and I can't figure out what template it is. It looks *vaguely* similar to this post: [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to replicate the style of the header, more specifically the size of the font and the type of the font.

[image]

http://www.wiwi.uni-jena.de/uiw/publications/pub_before_1999/Audretsch_Fritsch_1994b.pdf

I'm trying to replicate this document in TeX.

This is what I have so far.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle} 

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,tracking=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}


\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
%\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

\title{Fancy title goes here.}
\author{Author name}
\date{November $21^{st}$, 2012}                                           % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\rule[1cm]{17cm}{0.01cm}
\end{center}

\abstract{This paper will assess various aspects of a certain topic. \lipsum[24]}
\bigskip

\noindent Keywords: Something blah geography


\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsubsection*{\centerline{\bf{INTRODUCTION}}}

\lipsum[1-10]


\end{multicols}






\end{document}
```

Comment: Taylor & Francis has Word templates [here](http://journalauthors.tandf.co.uk/benefits/authorTemplates.asp) but I'm not sure what you are asking and how it relates to TeX?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this document in TeX (I edited the question)

Comment: Which aspects are you struggling to replicate? What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate all of it. I updated my question based on the feedback I received.

Comment: Please, notice that a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). In its current form, your question tend to get closed as "too 
localized". If you identify one specific issue in your attempt to replicate this design, you'll probably get more answers.

Comment: I updated my answer again, I included a very specific issue that I need. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: To identify a font see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/627 In this case the header uses Bembo.

Answer (score 2):

I like old, beautiful fonts, too.  I looked through my library in search of some that bear a resemblance to what you have there.  I found a few, some more so some less so.  While fonts themselves are not really TeX questions, the relevance to my response is that I wrote the programs to install these fonts onto my LaTeX installation, as detailed in [Displaying medieval scriptures and neumes in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943#100943) .  Anyhow, here is a pic of those fontsets, none of which are an exact match to your example:

[image]

The fonts are identified by name above the image.  For them, I have no small caps, so the author names look nothing like the original.